# LinkedList remove at index java

Tags: java, linked-list

I've made a remove method from scratch that removes a Node from a linked list at a specified index.

It's not removing the correct Node. I've tried to step through with the debugger in eclipse but couldn't catch the problem.

Each Node contains a token.
I have included the Token class, Node class.
I have written my methods in the List class and included a Test class.

The remove method is currently removing the node next to the specified index.
How can I get this to work? My apologies for the long post.

```
public class thelist{

    public Node head;

    public List() {
        head = null;
    }

    public Node remove(int index) {
        Node node= head;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            node= node.next;
        }
        node.next = node.next.next;
        return node;
    }
```

Comment: `ref.next = ref.next.next;` Should that be `ref.previous.next = ref.next;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that once you get to the correct index, you're removing the NEXT node, not the one at the index. Once you find the correct node, you can to set `ref.previous.next` to `ref.next`; thus, cutting out `ref`.

```
public Token remove(int index) {
    if (index<0 || index >=size()) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    Node ref = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        ref = ref.next;
    }
    if (index == 0) {
        head = ref.next;
    } else {
        ref.previous.next = ref.next;
    }
    size--;
    return ref.getObject();
}
```

Comment: You will get an error when `index` is `0`. Assuming `head.previous` is `null`.

Comment: This would get a NPE if you tried removing the last index, where `ref.next` is null, or the first index where`ref.previous` is also null, so you need to check for those and handle those cases accordingly.

Comment: Yes, `index` of `0` would throw a `NullPointerException`, which I've corrected. However, if it was the last index, it would not throw an expection because `ref.next` would just reference null, not try to access a property of null.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now

Comment: Also, I see that the original code throws because `List.add(Node)` never actually sets `node.previous`. Set that, and you should get not exceptions.

Comment: How can I set node.previous?

Comment: In your `add` method, when you after you set `tail.next` to a new node, set `tail.next.previous` to `tail`, and then result `tail` to `tail.next`. Essentially, when you add a new node, you need to add the reference to the previous node.

Answer (score 0):

Remove by index

```
public boolean remove(int index) {
     
    // if the index is out of range, exit
    if(index>size|| index <=0){
        return false;
    }
    if (index == 1 ){
        head = head.next;
    }

    Node crunchifyCurrent = head;
    if (head != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < index-2; i++) {
            crunchifyCurrent = crunchifyCurrent.next;
        }
            if (crunchifyCurrent.next == null){
                return false;
            }else{
        
        crunchifyCurrent.next = crunchifyCurrent.next.next;
            }
        // decrement the number of elements variable
        size--;
        return true;

    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be another solution.

```java
   public E remove(int index) {
            if (index >= size || index < 0) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index: " + index + ", Size " + index);
            }
    
            Node current = head;
    
            if (index == 0) {
                size--;
                head = current.next;
                return (E) current.element;
            }
    
            Node temp = null;
            for (int i = 1; i <= index; i++) {
                temp = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
    
            temp.next = current.next;
            size--;
    
            return (E) current.element;
        }
```

Test cases:

```java
    @Test
    void removeByIndex() {
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add("a");
        String element = list.remove(0);
        Assertions.assertEquals("a",element);
        Assertions.assertEquals(0,list.size());
    
        list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add("a");
        list.add("b");
        element = list.remove(1);
        Assertions.assertEquals("b",element);
        Assertions.assertEquals("a",list.get(0));
        Assertions.assertEquals(1,list.size());
    
        list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add("a");
        list.add("b");
        list.add("c");
        element = list.remove(1);
        Assertions.assertEquals("b",element);
        Assertions.assertEquals("a",list.get(0));
        Assertions.assertEquals("c",list.get(1));
        Assertions.assertEquals(2,list.size());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   public void Atposition(E pos){
    Node<E> curr = head, prev = null;
    if(curr!=null&&curr.getElement()==pos){
    curr=head;
    head=head.getNext();
    size--;
    return;
}while(curr!=null&&curr.getElement()!=pos){
    prev = curr;
    curr=curr.getNext();
}
if(curr==null){
    System.out.print("the list is empty");
    return;
}
    prev.next=curr.next;
}
```